# Parse JSON response to populate data in the form of table

Tags: python, json, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

I have JSON response in a `<class 'dict'>`. I want to iterate over the JSON response and form a table view. Below is the sample JSON response.

```
{'ResultSet': {'Rows': [{'Data': [{'VarCharValue': 'cnt'}, {'VarCharValue': 'id'}, {'VarCharValue': 'val'}]}, {'Data': [{'VarCharValue': '2000'}, {'VarCharValue': '1234'}, {'VarCharValue': 'ABC'}]},{'Data': [{'VarCharValue': '3000'}, {'VarCharValue': '5678'}, {'VarCharValue': 'DEF'}]}]}}
```

**Expected Output format:**

```
 cnt    id     val
2000   1234    ABC
3000   5678    DEF
```

There can only one row of data or there can be multiple rows of data for the column set (For provided sample data two rows are there).

Comment: Which part exactly are you stuck on?

Comment: I have sure how to iterate over the multiple rows, there can be n number of rows.

Comment: I see you added a #python hashtag to your question.  If you are using Python, can you provide your python code so we can see where you are having problems?

Comment: @EricMilliot-Martinez, I want to achieve this requirement in python.

Comment: @user805 SO isn't a place for people to write code for you, we help troubleshoot errors you may be having. Try yourself first.

Comment: @user805 Since you haven't provided us with any of your code where you tried attempting to solve this, I suggest you google for some examples.  A quick google brought me this and maybe this will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36862308/how-to-create-a-table-with-data-from-json-output-in-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want to use Pandas. Since `pd.DataFrame` accepts a list of dictionaries directly, you can restructure your input dictionary `D` as a list of dictionaries:

```
cols = [next(iter(i.values())) for i in D['ResultSet']['Rows'][0]['Data']]

d = [{col: j['VarCharValue'] for col, j in zip(cols, i['Data'])}
     for i in D['ResultSet']['Rows'][1:]]

df = pd.DataFrame(d)

print(df)

    cnt    id  val
0  2000  1234  ABC
1  3000  5678  DEF
```

You will probably want to convert at least the `cnt` series to numeric:

```
df['cnt'] = pd.to_numeric(df['cnt'])
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you are using `pandas` but you can easily parse your `response` dict into a `pandas.DataFrame` with the following code

```
import pandas as pd

pd.DataFrame([[entr['VarCharValue'] for entr in r['Data']] for r in response['ResultSet']['Rows'][1:]],
             columns = [r['VarCharValue'] for r in response['ResultSet']['Rows'][0]['Data']])
```