# Deeply nested json - a list within a dictionary to Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to parse nested json results.

```
data = {
"results": [
        {
            "components": [
                {
                    "times": {
                            "periods": [
                                {
                                    "fromDayOfWeek": 0,
                                    "fromHour": 12,
                                    "fromMinute": 0,
                                    "toDayOfWeek": 4,
                                    "toHour": 21,
                                    "toMinute": 0,
                                    "id": 156589,
                                    "periodId": 20855
                                }
                            ],
                        }
                    }
                ],
            }
        ],
    }
```

I can get to and create dataframes for "results" and "components" lists, but cannot get to "periods" due to the "times" dict. So far I have this:

df =  pd.json_normalize(data, record_path = ['results','components'])

Need a separate "periods" dataframe with the included column names and values. Would appreciate your help on this. Thank you!

Comment: Why not `df = pd.json_normalize(data, record_path = ['results','components', 'times', 'periods'])`?

Comment: @jlesuffleur you're right, it works. i simplified this example here, but learned that the error wasn't from the json.normalize, but from the loop. thanks for the comment!

Answer (score 0):

- I results
- II  components
- III times
- IIII  periods

The normalize should be correct way:

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html

There is 4 level of nesting. There can be x components in results and y times in components - however that type of nesting is overengineering?

The simplest way of getting data is:

```
print data['a']['b']['c']['d'] (...)
```

in your case:

print data['results']['components']['times']['periods']

---

You can access the specific nested level by this piece of code:

```
def GetPropertyFromPeriods (property):
    propertyList = []
    for x in data['results']['components']['times']:
        singleProperty = photoURL['periods'][property]
        propertyList.append(singleProperty)
    return propertyList
```

This give you access to one property inside periods (fromDayOfWeek, fromHour, fromMinute)

After coverting json value, transform it into pandas dataframe:

```
print pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["columnA", "columnB”])
```

---

If stuck:

[How to Create a table with data from JSON output in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36862308/how-to-create-a-table-with-data-from-json-output-in-python/36862989)

[Python - How to convert JSON File to Dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41168558/python-how-to-convert-json-file-to-dataframe)

pandas documentation:

- pandas.DataFrame.from_dict
- pandas.json_normalize

Comment: Hey Piotr, thanks for the answer. You're correct, it worked. My actual issue, unfortunately, isn't related to the nesting as I just learned, but from looping. I simplified the example here, but my actual code has a loop and it was throwing error for missing nests, which I'll have to solve first. Thank you for your answer tho - appreciate it!

Comment: the error was due to: the "times" sometimes doesn't have the "periods" list in it, so the loop I guess was not finding "periods" when I was iterating and trying to get to it.